# Facebook Login in Laravel 5

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-socialite

I have registered my application with facebook, is using the Laravel socialite package.

I'm unable to find a solution regarding how I should set up Facebook in the services.php file.

**services.php**

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('FB_APP_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FB_APP_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env(''), //???
],
```

Before I proceed I want to know which keys and values I need to provide in the facebook array and where I can find them. The first two, I believe, are correct but I'm uncertain about any other.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you got your APP_ID and APP_SECRET from your registered app on Facebook Developers website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this [article](http://tutsnare.com/social-authentication-in-laravel-5/) helpful, it details how to implement the Socialite package quite well.

As for your setup, it all looks fine for the ID side of things, however the redirect should be set to the call-back URL you wish to use. E.g `www.yoursite.com/account/facebook`.

You can then pick this up in your `routes.php` file and direct it to a controller function.

Comment: I'm currently reading that article but the guy is using github. What I want to know if whether that 'redirect' item in the array is correct and whether there are any other items I need to include.

Comment: At the moment you need to specify in the `redirect` part of the array where it should look in your `.env` file. E.g `'redirect' => env('FB_REDIRECT'),` and then specify that in your `.env` file. Alternatively, remove the `env` reference and just use `'redirect' => 'http://yoursite.com/account/facebook',`.

Answer (score 0):

Helo Just make sure you go to 'setting' tabs on your facebook APP account then click 'advaced' tabs there you can see 'Valid OAuth redirect URIs' this is be your callback url of your site like http://example.com/callback/ then the url should be set same like this at your code

'redirect' => env('http://example.com/callback/')

hope this can help your problem :)

Comment: I'm busy trying that, thank you. Is using 'localhost' valid or will I run into trouble?

Comment: if you setup callback url correctly your code will working as you need and just make sure it will not work over localhost